# vagrant freezes after a while

Tags: linux, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile

Using Vagrant for development, the VM freezes after a while working with it. I have to reload the box in order to be able to work with it again. The file is very simple and straightforward:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial32"

  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.68.8"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
          v.memory = 8192
          v.cpus = 2
      end
  config.vm.synced_folder "./", "/var/www/html", owner: "www-data", group: "www-data"
  config.ssh.insert_key = false

  config.vm.provision :shell, path: "config/vagrant/bootstrap.sh"
end
```

and config/vagrant/bootstrap.sh looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Variables
DBNAME=dbname
DBUSER=dbuser
DBPASSWD=dbpassword

apt-get -y install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php
apt-get update


apt-get update

debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password password $DBPASSWD"
debconf-set-selections <<< "mysql-server mysql-server/root_password_again password $DBPASSWD"

apt-get -y install mysql-server
sed -i "s/.*bind-address.*/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/mysqld.cnf

mysql -uroot -p$DBPASSWD -e "CREATE DATABASE $DBNAME"
mysql -uroot -p$DBPASSWD -e "grant all privileges on $DBNAME.* to '$DBUSER'@'%' identified by '$DBPASSWD'"
mysql -uroot -p$DBPASSWD -e "flush privileges"

sudo apt-get -y install apache2 php7.4 php7.4-mysql php7.4-mbstring php7.4-dom php7.4-sqlite php7.4-zip php7.4-curl php7.4-intl

sudo apt-get -y install curl composer zip unzip

sudo phpenmod pdo_mysql
sudo service apache2 restart
sudo service mysql restart
```

I read a blog post that suggests removing `config.ssh.insert_key = false` as a solution but this does not work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

there is no output. It works as expected for approximately 15 minutes before the entire box freezes and stops responding (no response to shell input as well as no `vagrant ssh`).

Comment: You forgot to include Vagrant output.

Comment: there is no output. It works as expected for approximately 15 minutes before the entire box freezes and stops responding (no response to shell input as well as no `vagrant ssh`).

Comment: Have you checked vbox' logs for that virtual machine? Also, i assume `vagrant reload` ends up doing force shutdown?

Comment: hm, where to check these logs? yes, vagrant reload helps but doing this almost every 10-15 minutes is annoying.

Comment: Please step up your search skills in spare time: https://docs.oracle.com/en/virtualization/virtualbox/6.0/admin/vboxconfigdata.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I found the issue.

I have changed this line:

```
      v.cpus = 2
```

to

```
      v.cpus = 1
```

and I had no hang ups the whole day.